# Modeling suggestions given ACF and PACF

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I am interested in fitting a basic ARMA model to some data. The ACF and PACF graphs are as follows:

[image]

[image]

My first, potentially naive thought, was to fit an autoregressive model:

$x_t=\alpha x_{t-24}+\varepsilon_t$,

however, I am not sure how to do this in R. Fitting a ar model of order 24 fits all intermediate autoregressive terms:

```
arima(y,order=c(24,0,0))
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Please post the actual data .

Comment: You can fix the desired parameters to zero by using the argument `fixed` in the function `arima`. The argument `fixed` should be a numeric vector of the same length as the total number of parameters. If supplied, only `NA` entries in `fixed` will be varied. Thus use `fixed=c(rep(0,23),NA,NA)` where the last `NA` is for the intercept. Also, your model will likely be a bit too simple since there are many significant ACFs and PACFs in between zero and 24. You might try the function `auto.arima` from the "forecast" package.

Comment: Since it solved your problem, I reposted the comment as an answer (you may accept it if you like). I also fixed the formula for the AR(24) model in your post by appending the missing error term.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the desired parameters to zero by using the argument `fixed` in the function `arima`. The argument `fixed` should be a numeric vector of the same length as the total number of parameters. If supplied, only `NA` entries in `fixed` will be varied. Thus use `fixed=c(rep(0,23),NA,NA)` where the last `NA` is for the intercept.

Also, your model will likely be a bit too simple since there are many significant autocorrelations and partial autocorrelations in between zero and 24. You might try the function `auto.arima` from the "forecast" package. If your data is seasonal (there seems to be a period 24), you may try a seasonal ARIMA model.